# Extend an XML schema with custom elements

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to do the following:

```
<myNamespace:foo>
    <myNamespace:bar>hello</myNamespace:bar>
    <myNamespace:extended>
        <yourNamespace:anything>
        ....
        </yourNamespace:anything>
    </myNamespace:extended>
</myNamespace:foo>
```

Essentially, I want to design a schema that will allow a particular element to be overridden with elements from another namespace.

I've tried this:

```
<!-- mySchema.xsd -->
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/mySchema" 
    xmlns:myNamespace="http://www.example.org/mySchema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <complexType name="extendedType">
        <sequence>
            <any/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <element name="foo">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="bar" type="string"/>
                <element name="extended" type="myNamespace:extendedType"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
```

.

```
<!-- yourSchema.xsd -->
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/yourSchema" 
    xmlns:yourNamespace="http://www.example.org/yourSchema"
    xmlns:myNamespace="http://www.example.org/mySchema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <import namespace="http://www.example.org/mySchema" schemaLocation="mySchema.xsd"/>

    <redefine schemaLocation="mySchema.xsd">
        <complexType name="extendedType">
                <complexContent>
                <extension base="myNamespace:extendedType">
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="anything"></element>
                    </sequence>
                </extension>
            </complexContent>
        </complexType>
    </redefine>
</schema>
```

but when I try to create a new document from yourSchema.xsd, i get the following in eclipse:  "No root element exists since the schema provided has no global elements".  Shouldn't yourSchema.xsd inherit the root element from mySchema.xsd?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is to define the `<extended>` element with the type `anyType`. Try this schema out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"     attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="foo">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="bar" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="extended" type="xs:anyType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```